# Spring XML from existing beans - how?

Tags: java, xml, spring, dependency-injection, code-generation

I have java beans:

```
package com.denisk.beans;
...
public class SomeBean {
    private String someProperty;
    private AnotherBean anotherBean;
    ...
}

public class AnotherBean {
    private String anotherProperty;
    ....
}
```

I want to generate a *stub* xml spring configuration for these beans, something like

```
<beans>
    <bean id="someBean">
        <property name="someProperty" value="sldfjslkdfjas;lfj"/>
        <property name="anotherBean" ref="anotherBean"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="anotherBean">
        <property name="anotherProperty" value="klj;df;ksdjflsjkd;lfj"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I want this to be done using some tool, which would accept a path to my beans as an input, like that:

```
denisk@denisk-work:~$ generateSpringXml -p "/home/denisk/myProject/src/main/java/com/denisk/beans" -output "/home/denisk/mySpringConfig.xml"
```

Shouldn't be a big deal, but I can't google out anything like that.

Thanks

Comment: Thats a sort-of interesting task, but I wonder what's the point. If you have an app not using DI, you still will have to code a lot to change it, an appcontext xml will not solve anything. Can you tell what's intention exactly?

Comment: I want to create integration tests. I want the data to be filled by spring. I would save the data into the database and use the same spring config to verify that it was saved correctly. The problem is that there are two or three hundred entities, and there is much work to write spring config for them by hand. I would like to generate stub and edit it afterwards - that would save me two or three days of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out:

https://github.com/mangstadt/Spring-Application-Context-Generator

This will take a list of Java classes and generate the XML bean definitions for them.  It generates a `<bean />` element for each public class, a `<property />` element for each public field and setter method, and a list of `<constructor-arg />` elements if there is only one constructor and that constructor is not the default constructor.

Example:

```
java com.mangst.appcontext.ApplicationContextGenerator --source=/home/denisk/myProject/src/main/java --package=com.denisk.beans
```

If you try this out, let me know if there are any problems so I can make improvements.

Comment: Wow, it works! And you have written it by yourself - you rock man! Can this be tweaked a bit to go recursively through packages?

Comment: @denisk Yes, ok, try now with `--recurse` flag.

Comment: That's great, thanks! Your tool is very neat. Have you considered adding ant or maven builds for it?

Comment: @denisk Hmm, yes, adding ant/maven improves building process.

Comment: Awesome package! Thanks! One small request - can you include the JDK compile target in you POM? I think you are using 6+